# Meaning of “as” in “does not have to be as healthy"

Tags: word-meaning

What does "as" mean in article below?

> President Trump is the president of the USA. President Obama was the president before him. When Obama is president, he makes stronger food rules for schools. He wants the food to be healthy.
>
> Trump’s administration has different ideas. People change these food rules. The school food does not have to be **as** healthy. Last Wednesday, some states sue the Trump administration.
>
> Michelle Obama is President Obama’s First Lady. She helps make the stronger rules. She asks why the government makes the changes. She asks why the government does not want children to have good food at school.

Answer (score 1):

It means that Trump thinks that the food given to kids in school **doesn't have to meet the same health standards** that Obama thought it did in his administration.

Comment: I don't see why this essentially correct answer was down voted. I wish people would not down vote without making a relevant comment unless a comment describing the concern is already in place. I have upvoted to compensate.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Kaique correctly describes the meaning of "as healthy"  in this passage. However, the passage has many grammatical problems and non-standard usages. A corrected version might be:

> President Trump is the president of the United States. President Obama was the president before him. When Obama was president, he made the food rules for schools stronger . He wanted the food to be healthy.
>
> Trump’s administration has different ideas. They changed these food rules, so that the school food does not have to be as healthy. Last Wednesday, some states sued the Trump administration.
>
> Michelle Obama was President Obama’s First Lady. She helped make the stronger rules. She asks why the government has made the changes. She asks why the government does not want children to have good food at school.

Comment: Why was this answer downvoted? without a comment, thre is no way to improve it or respond to any concern.

Comment: Don't let these people get to you, they downvote your answers just to piss you off.

Comment: I haven't downvoted this, but I would guess it's because it doesn't answer the question, but rather goes off on a tangent. Though that can't be a problem with the other answer, which was also downvoted.